# Flutter Class 'Productlist' has no instance method '[]'. Receiver: Instance of 'Productlist' Tried calling: []("price")

Tags: flutter, provider

I HAVE A PROBLEM I WANT TO PUT MAY DATA PROVIDER result INTO a list. So that I can filter the data, I want to convert it to the list.
this is the result of the error:

```
I/flutter (32434): [Instance of 'Productlist', Instance of 'Productlist', Instance of 'Productlist', Instance of 'Productlist', Instance of 'Productlist', Instance of 'Productlist', Instance of 'Productlist', Instance of 'Productlist', Instance of 'Productlist', Instance of 'Productlist', Instance of 'Productlist', Instance of 'Productlist', Instance of 'Productlist', Instance of 'Productlist', Instance of 'Productlist']
```

This is the error after I use this code:

```
 productfiltered = productdata.where((productx) => productx['price'] == '2000').toList();
```

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
Class 'Productlist' has no instance method '[]'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Productlist'
Tried calling: []("price")
```

This is my code:

```
class FeaturedCard2 extends StatelessWidget {

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
List productdata = [];
    
List productfiltered = [];

    final products = Provider.of<List<Productlist>>(context);

    productdata = products;
    productfiltered = productdata;

    print(productfiltered);
    productfiltered = productdata.where((productx) => productx['price'] == '2000').toList();

    return Container();
  }
}
```

[this is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az0rz.jpg)

I want the result like this:

```
 [{productname: numarkxx, qty: 2, price: 1000,productname: numarkxx, qty: 2, price: 1000, productname: numarkxx, qty: 2, price: 1000}]
```

Comment: please use github gist's to post robust error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your product model class will look like this:

```
class ProductModel {
  String productname;
  int qty;
  int price;

  ProductModel({this.productname, this.qty, this.price});

  ProductModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    productname = json['productname'];
    qty = json['qty'];
    price = json['price'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['productname'] = this.productname;
    data['qty'] = this.qty;
    data['price'] = this.price;
    return data;
  }
}
```

And then, you don't need to define any unnecessary productdata variable. You can simply check and filter the array with the price like this:

```
class FeaturedCard2 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List productfiltered = [];

    final products = Provider.of<List<ProductModel>>(context);

    productfiltered = products;

    print(productfiltered);
    productfiltered =
        products.where((productx) => productx.price == 2000).toList(); // Here is important!

    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: how to use toJson() sir?

Comment: this is my http request  Future<List<Productlist>> getProducts2() async {
    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    map["action"] = "FETCHPRODUCT";
    var response = await http.post('http://10.0.2.2/A_TEST/?apix32=api-products', body: map);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body) as List;

      return jsonResponse
          .map((product) => Productlist.fromJson(product))
          .toList();
    } else {
      print("getproduct2 error status");
      throw List<Productlist>();
    }
  }

Comment: one more sir 
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FeaturedCard2(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<List<ProductModel>>]):
The method 'where' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: where(Closure: (ProductModel) => bool)